# css menu 2nd line indent without compromising background hover colour indent too

Tags: html, css, submenu

so pretty simple but also pretty annoying as I can't seem to detach the colour on the hover away from the styling of the 2nd line of the text of the 2nd menu item "family therapy ---"

i want to have the menu look like the first menu but with the 2nd line of text aligned like the rest of the menu items.... I have included pictures to be as clear as possible...

BEFORE ---

[image: THIS IS WITH THE MOUSE HOVERING OVER THE MENU ITEM I JUST WISH I COULD INDENT THE 2ND LINE TEXT]

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR BUT IT STOPS THE HOVER COLOUR SPANNING ACCROSS THE SPACE ON THE LEFT AND I DON'T WANT TO DO THAT , ONLY INDENT THE 2ND LINE OF TEXT.[image]

The css currently looks like this...

```
}
 #subnav ul li
 {
background:#5c0917;
line-height:28px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
border-top:1px solid #fff;
outline: none;
list-style-position: outside;


}
#subnav ul li a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
display:block;
outline: none; 
text-align:left;
text-indent:15px;


}
#subnav ul li a:hover
{
background:#d40203;
outline: none; 



}

#subnav ul li#active
{
background:#d40203;
outline: none;

}

#subnav ul li#subtwo {color:#ffffff ;}

#subnav ul li#subone a:hover{color:#ffffff; background-color: #1e3435;}
#subnav ul li#subtwo a:hover{color:#ffffff; background-color: #33342b;text-align:left;}
#subnav ul li#subthree a:hover{color:#ffffff; background-color: #34212b;}
#subnav ul li#subfour a:hover{color:#ffffff; background-color: #1e2141;}
#subnav ul li#subfive a:hover{color:#ffffff; background-color: #301e41;}
```

Comment: what about making fiddle?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving `text-indent`, give `padding-left: 15px`. So, your style for `#subnav ul li a` should be:

```
#subnav ul li a {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Remove `text-indent: 15px` from it.